# How to add Samsung Iap SDK to android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, in-app-purchase, samsung-mobile-sdk

Im an android developer, my experience in using android studio isn't very high. Im really stuck on how should I include/ import the Samsung In app purchase on my project. I have downloaded this SDK "SamsungInAppPurchaseSDK_v6.1" from the official page of Samsung, but dont know how to do the next step.

I have read many pages but didnt understand how to include this SDK.
pages I have read :
https://developer.samsung.com/iap/programming-guide/iap-helper-programming.html
https://developer.samsung.com/sdp/blog/en-us/2021/03/05/ensuring-secure-purchases-using-the-samsung-iap-server-api
https://developer.samsung.com/sdp/blog/en-us/2021/03/10/integration-of-samsung-iap-services-in-android-apps
and many more.

If any one is an experienced user and know how I can import this SDK to android studio, it would be very helpful your solution.
Thank you

Comment: Just like any other sdk you need first add it to your project to be able to use it, the steps are provided here - https://developer.samsung.com/iap/programming-guide/integrate-iap-helper-into-your-app.html#Add-the-IAP-Helper-to-your-app

Answer (score 0):

you can import the SDK(IAP6Helper) directory in AndroidStudio.

1. Click File → New → Import module.
2. Select the IAP6Helper folder from the Source Directory, and click Finish.
3. From Project Explorer, click Open Module Settings or press F4 → Dependencies tab.
4. Select your app module, and click + → Module Dependency from Declared Dependencies.
5. Select the IAP6Helper module, and click OK.